# SQL comma separated column loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a serious problem with SQL that already took me 3 hours. I have two tables like these:

First table: **Employees**

```
ID | NAME
---+--------
 1 | John
 2 | Mike
 3 | Robert
```

Second table: **Customers**

```
 ID | NAME    | EMPLOYEES 
 ---+---------+--------------
  1 | Michael | 2,3
  2 | Julia   | 1
  3 | Mila    | 1,2,3
```

I want the output like this:

```
Michael | Mike, Robert
Julia   | John
Mila    | John, Mike, Robert
```

What should the SQL command to get the expected output?

Comment: Clearly the original problem is the table design. Fix the structure first. You should not store comma separated values in a column. Then the query will be a simple `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Prdp my EMPLOYEE_ID column is nvarchar. edited the post. Thx

Comment: But it should be the same datatype of `Employees` table `ID` column also it should be referenced from `Employees` table `ID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select A.Name
      ,Employees  = (Select Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +Name From Employees Where charindex(','+cast(ID as varchar(25))+',',','+A.EMPLOYEE_ID+',')>0 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )
 From Customers A
```

Returns

```
Name    Employees
Michael Mike,Robert
Julia   John
Mila    John,Mike,Robert
```

Comment: @Guest Happy to help

Comment: @Guest you will have a hard time when the table grows. It will be a nightmare to optimize the queries with this structure

Comment: @Guest Gordon and Prdp are absolutely correct.  ... More normalized... More better

Answer (score 4):

This is an awful data structure and you should fix it.  That is the primary thing.  Storing numbers as strings is bad.  Storing multiple values in a column is bad.  Not declaring foreign key relationships is bad.

That said, what can you do if someone else set up such a database and did so in this bad way?  Well, you can do:

```
select c.*, e.name
from customers c join
     employees e
     on ',' + cast(e.id as varchar(255)) + ',' like '%,' + c.employee_id + ',%';
```

Note that this query cannot be optimized using normal SQL methods, such as indexes, because the `JOIN` condition is too complicated.

This will give you more rows than you have asked for:

```
Michael    Mike
Michael    Robert
Julia      John
Mila       John
Mila       Mike
Mila       Robert
```

However, this is the normal way that SQL works, so you should get used to it.

Comment: Bro now I can't change the table structure, but I'll change it at next update.  Thank you a lot

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, why we must create foreign key between two tables? Referential integrity is the main thing. Other than that any advantages like query performance we can get when we create foreign key?